# disable Camera auto settings using open CV

Tags: c++, windows, image, opencv, camera

I've been working for a while with openCV on windows and tried using the capture.set() function.
I know there have been issues setting whitebalance and exposure. I especially have an issue with disabling the auto_mode in the camera.

I tried disabling using `capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_AUTO_EXPOSURE,0/1)` but it does not work. The only way that I found to disable the auto settings of the webcam was by the camera gui and unchecking the autosettings option.

Is there an easy way to read and write all the camera settings (and autosettings) by code (cpp) ? Most importantly a generic approach that isn't hardware specific.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no. I asked this question myself, when I tried to turn off autofocus for webcam calibration. You can't change anything by cpp code, only with driver software.